# Drupal update to specific version (not dev) with git

Tags: updating

I have a Drupal folder made with command:

```
git clone --branch 7.x https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git
```

Now I want to update it to the actual version (7.67). When I run

```
git pull origin 7.x
```

or

```
git pull origin 7.67
```

Every time I get the 7.68-dev version, not 7.67. What am I doing wrong?
I know how to get the specific version with composer, but in this situation I need to get it with git pull command.

Comment: Did you checkout 7.67 after you pulled the branch down?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! It seems it works now perfectly with command git pull origin 7.67 . I found out I was misled by the line about "dev-version" in CHANGELOG.txt. Despite of this line the version was 7.67, not 7.68)) So  the problem is fixed))

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on this for future reference:

Releases in git are created as tags.  To see the available releases, do the initial pull from the repo, then you can see the available tags with the command:

```
git tag
```

To check out the specific release, do:

```
git checkout [tag-id]
```

You will see a message about previous head and current head.

Check that you are on the correct tag with:

```
git status
```

It should indicate that you are currently in a headless state.